# Wildcards don't appear to be working in Bash

Tags: bash, files, wildcards

My `bash` shell has started acting weirdly when using wildcards. Tab-completions work and, if I type the file name in, it also works. But, if I use a wildcard, it does not work, as per the below transcript:

```
[~/myDir] ls JourneyManager.cpp 
JourneyManager.cpp
[~/myDir] ls JourneyManager.*
ls: cannot access 'JourneyManager.*': No such file or directory
```

I've examined the `ls` output and confirmed the file name is as expected, no weird character or anything. It's in a `git` repo but I don't think that's the issue since copies of the files in my home directory also have the same problem.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $-`? does it include `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this resolves the issue:

`set +f`

P.S.

Probably you should check the contents of your system and user profiles. There is a good article for this https://www.tecmint.com/understanding-shell-initialization-files-and-user-profiles-linux/

Comment: Ah, I think I figured out what happened, I have a vague recollection of doing `set -f` sometime yesterday to try get a list of functions.I should have use `declare`.